# Groovy - List conversion

Tags: groovy

new in Groovy and I have a problem with lists.

I have following

values = ["Value"]

after using ${values.getClass()} I have result java.util.ArrayList

for using API correctly it has to be java.util.List

could you please help me transform this string? Thanks

Comment: `ArrayList` implements `List` interface. You can also specify different `List` implementations https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-lists

Comment: In other words it's already a `List`. Show the error and code, so, we could help you.

Comment: try `List.isAssignableFrom( values.getClass() )` and see what you have to do to convert an `ArrayList` to `List`